# Uwamp - V 3.1 - Php 7.0.3 - Error [simple fix]

Tags: apache, uwamp

Just to let you know there seems to be an issue with the latest version, when selecting the php 7 option, it loads the httpd.conf rather the httd-uwamp.conf file, so cant find the php7xxxx.dll and will stop from apache from working / loading.

thanks

Comment: This is Q/A website, not a wiki

Answer (score 0):

removing the double-quotes form the httpd_uwamp.conf file worked for me on both UnWamp and PHP distributions. (No spaces are in any of my path names)

i.e.
change 
LoadModule "{PHPMODULENAME} {PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"

to
LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} {PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}

Answer (score 0):

You should install **redistributable Visual C++ 2015 x86** version on your system. Previous versions don't work well with php7. [You can download it here](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.